# Prove that a random variable follows MA(1) process

Tags: time-series, self-study, random-variable, covariance, moving-average

I have the follow variable
$$y_t = e_t + u_t + \theta u_{t-1}$$
Here $u_t$ and $e_t$ are mutually independent i.i.d
and $u_t \sim N(0, \sigma_u^2)$ and $e_t \sim N(0, \sigma_e^2)$.

I am trying to show that I can re-write $y_t$ as an MA(1) process, i.e. : $y_t = \lambda_t + \phi\lambda_{t-1}$ where $\{\lambda_t\}$ are iid with mean zero and normal with variance $\sigma_{\lambda}^2$.
I thought we could calculate the autocovariance function to prove that but I wasn't successful.

Also, I'd like to find some expressions for $ \phi$ and $\sigma_{\lambda}^2$.

Comment: I have added the [tag:self-study] tag. Please see its scope and requirements.

Comment: Your "thought" is actually effective -- by "*I wasn't successful*", do you mean you cannot calculate the autocovariance function or you cannot reach the final conclusion?  If not the former, you can show us what autocovariance function you have gotten.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, I will generalize to $u_t$ ~ N(0,1) and $e_t$ ~ N(0,1).

Cov[$Y_t$,$Y_{t-1}$] =
E[$Y_t$,$Y_{t-1}$] =
E[($e_t$ + $u_t$ + $\theta$$u_{t-1}$) ($e_{t-k}$ + $u_{t-k}$ + $\theta$$u_{t-k-1}$)]

After expanding, you will have a total of 9 terms inside E[]. Let's call this S.

For k=0, S = E[$e_{t}^2$ +$u_{t}^2$+$\theta^2$$u_{t-1}^2$], this is obviously Variance of $Y_t$, where Var[$Y_t$]=2+$\theta^2$

For k=1, S = E[$\theta$ $u_{t-1}^2$], this is so because $e_t$ and $u_t$ are i.i.d. and are mutually independent. This gives you S=$\theta$

For k=2, S = 0, since there are no terms like $u_{t-k}^2$ or $u_{t}^2$ or $e_{t-k}^2$ or $e_{t}^2$.

Autocovariance (or Autocorrelation if you like) collapses to zero at k=2, thus $Y_t$ is a MA(1) process.

To find expression for $\phi$, use

$\phi$/(1+$\phi^2$) =  $\theta$/(2+$\theta^2$)

And solve for $\phi$ algebraically